# Does $δS = 0$ mean that "the small changes in the actions equal to zero"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What I understood from the Principle of Stationary Action is that for an object moving from point A to point B, at every point of the path with the least action, the actions are the same, so the small differences in the actions equal to zero, hence $δS = 0$.

So, kind of like this, where the $ΔS = 0$;

[image]

I feel very suspicious about my understanding, so I'd appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the diagram you show is not correct, since you are interpreting variations of the action along the curve that minimizes it (sorry if I misunderstood the picture), and that is not the point of the principle of stationary action.

Let me give you the general idea. Consider the case of a single particle moving in 3D space between a given pair of points $a$ and $b$. Let me denote as $\vec{X}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ an arbitrary path connecting them, i.e., such that $\vec{X}(0)=a$ and $\vec{X}(1)=b$. Conceptually, you have to keep in mind that the action $S$ is a number associated to the entire curve and not to little pieces of it. In other words, each curve $\vec{X}(t)$ between $a$ and $b$ has an associated value of the action $S$, some real number.

---

Now imagine that the curve $\vec{X}(t)$ is some kind of elastic string nailed to $a$ and $b$ and you perform a little deformation of it, giving rise to a new curve $\vec{X}'(t) = \vec{X}(t) + \epsilon \vec{v}(t)$ (where $\epsilon$ is small and $\vec{v}(0)=\vec{v}(1)=0$ to keep $\vec{X}'$ nailed to $a$ and $b$). Check the diagram in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle).

The point of the principle of stationary action is that if $\vec{X}$ is the physical trajectory, you will find that the action changes just by a little when we deform $\vec{X}$ into $\vec{X}'$, and in such a way that if you perform smaller and smaller deformations ($\epsilon \to 0$), the relative change of the action $\Delta S/\epsilon$ tends to zero.

It is basically the same that happens in real analysis when you are at a point $x=x_0$ at which a given function $f(x)$ has vanishing derivative $f'(x_0)=0$, i.e., that the function looks *flat* very close to this point. If you get closer and closer (i.e., in the limit $\epsilon \equiv x-x_0 \to 0$) the quantity $\Delta f/\epsilon$ goes to zero (which is the value of the derivative). Here the idea is the same but instead of moving $x$ you are moving the entire curve $\vec{X}(t)$.

I hope this helps.